# move_base won't subscribe to /scan topic

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am publishing laser scan data from another framework, but move_base won't subscribe to it. I know it is being published from `rostopic echo scan`. The sensor frame shows correctly in the tf_tree and I don't see why move_base wont subscribe to the topic.

Here is my `move_base.launch` file:

```
<launch>

  <master auto="start"/>
  <!-- Run the map server -->
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="/home/jm/isaac/sdk/packages/eband_ros/maps/factory.yaml"/>

  <!-- move_base -->
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">

    <rosparam file="$(find isaac_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find isaac_navigation)/param/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find isaac_navigation)/param/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />

    <param name="base_global_planner" type="string" value="navfn/NavfnROS" />
    <param name="base_local_planner" value="eband_local_planner/EBandPlannerROS" />

  </node>
</launch>
```

and here is my `costmap_common_params.yaml` file :

```
obstacle_range: 0.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
footprint: [[0.57, 0.75],[0.57, -0.75],[-1.153, -0.75],[-1.153, 0.75]]
inflation_radius: 0.25

observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor

laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: base_scan, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

I would like to upload the `rqt_graph` and the `rqt_tf_tree` pictures but i dont have enough points.

Thanks in advance for helping!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380940/move_base-won%27t-subscribe-to-/scan-topic/) by [jmyazbeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/74848/jmyazbeck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2021-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the [navigation tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup#Creating_a_Launch_File_for_the_Navigation_Stack), notice that `costmap_common_params.yaml` is loaded twice but in different namespaces:

```
<rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" /> 
<rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
```

In your case, you load the common parameters once without a namespace, so the parameters aren't where the two costmaps are looking for their parameters.  You can check the parameter definitions with:

```
rosparam list
```

With a correct setup, you should see the common parameters listed under each costmap's namespace, like:

```
...
/move_base/global_costmap/obstacles_layer/scan_1/clearing
/move_base/global_costmap/obstacles_layer/scan_1/data_type
...
/move_base/local_costmap/obstacles_layer/scan_1/clearing
/move_base/local_costmap/obstacles_layer/scan_1/data_type
...
```

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2021-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jmyazbeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/74848/jmyazbeck/) on 2021-06-24**:
Awesome, thank you so much. It makes sense and it worked!